# Verify if string contains valid Python code

Tags: python, validation, syntax

I am trying to check whether some string contains valid Python code, disregarding **any** context. Using [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) and [`codeop.compile_command`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codeop.html#codeop.compile_command) won't work for all cases, because:

- `ast.parse(x)` will throw a `SyntaxError` if it encounters incomplete code (e.g. `if True:`)
- `codeop.compile_command(x)` does not cover all cases of incomplete code; it works for cases where `x` is not valid *as-is*, but is a prefix of valid Python code (e.g. it works for `if True:`, but not for `else:`)

Is there a workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: If you consider incomplete code valid Python code then every string even an empty one contains Python code.

Comment: Hm, right. It can be part of larger statement which, as a whole, can be valid.

Comment: @AlexandruDinu if you are allowing incomplete code, the `xyz:` could easily be part of `if s == xyx: print('yes')`; `ast.parse` has no problem with that.

Comment: It *contains* a valid name and multiple empty strings, both are valid Python. Also considering it incomplete it could be the later part of a valid `if` (or other) line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, this cannot be accomplished, because some individual string which appears to be invalid can be part of a larger one which itself is valid Python code.